# Find connection string for connecting to MySQL Server 5.1.50 using OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, mysql, oledbconnection

I am interested how can I find the connection string in order to be able to connect to MySQL Server 5.1.50 using OleDbConnection(C#).

I used this auto generated string (after adding new data source in Visual Studio):

```
server=localhost;User Id=MyID;password=MyPassword;database=MyDatabase
```

but I always get the same error message:

```
An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.
```

I have tried different providers but neither of them seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't using the MySQL .NET connector? Anyways, I think you need to add 
`Provider=MySQL Provider;`  to your connection string.

try this as your connection string:

```
Provider=MySQL Provider;server=localhost;User Id=MyID;password=MyPassword;database=MyDatabase;
```

The MySQL.NET connector fully implements the ADO.NET interface. Every command is identical to using the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace.