# Vb.net make mySQL connection through normal Oledb connection object

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, connection, oledb

I am attempting / can I, make a database connection through a normal Oledb connection object, and connection string...?

I would like to keep my current database methods, already spent alot of time on them, and they all make use of the oledb connection object. I do not wish to "change" them, to use a different connection object when needed, nor do I wish to re-do all of them with a different connection object.

I am interfacing between an access db and a mySQL db.

```
Private db_cn As New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
```

'Access Conn String

```
cn_connection_string = "PROVIDER=MSDataShape;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****;Data Source=" & DbPath

db_cn = New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cn_connection_string)
```

Now, my mySQL conn string so far is this...

```
cn_connection_string = "Server=*****;Uid=*****;Pwd=******;Database=*****;"
```

Oledb reports that I am not specifying a "driver". If I do specify the driver I find in my server explorer connection string, oledb reports that its not registered.

My Server explorer does connect to the db successfully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT - 28-01-2013

Here is the exact error, on using the priovder as in the Server Explorer Properties.

"The '.NET Framework Data Provider for MySQL' provider is not registered on the local machine."

Connection String in Code is this:
cn_connection_string = "provider=.NET Framework Data Provider for MySQL;****;Uid=****;Pwd=****;Database=****;"

Connection String in Server Explorer is this:
server=****;User Id=****;database=****

Comment: can you give the actual error message about the `oledb reports that its not registered.`?

Comment: have you installed the [mySQL Connector](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)?

Comment: yup, as stated. I can make a connection to the mySQL db from the server explorer in the IDE

Comment: see http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#net-framework-data-provider-for-ole-db

Comment: been, ther done that, came from there.. :-)

Comment: this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919989/find-connection-string-for-connecting-to-mysql-server-5-1-50-using-oledbconnecti

Comment: Yeah. I have thus far ended up with the same conclusion... just re-did some code to cater for the mySQL connection Object, and its own methods and internal objects. Working good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're about to migrate, the `Ms Access` to `mySQL` or either, please take note that this two has a different libraries. So the short answer is **NO**

Comment: Thanks, whats the long answer? :-)

Comment: the long answer is all about to modify your codes from Ms Access to mySQL `:D`

Comment: I ended up using the mySQL object and adjusted my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In Server Explorer right click on the connection and choose properties.  The full connection string is there!

Comment: Yeah, thats what I mentioned in my original post... that does, however, not work in code...